# Eclipse - interactive shell for python not working

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've installed and configured Pydev with Eclipse but when I try to use interactive shell I get errors. Can someone have a look and advise?

Code for two functions:

```
def convert_milage(t):  # t - number of miles per 1 gallon
    litersPer100Kilometers = 100/ ((t * 1.609) / 3.785) 
    return litersPer100Kilometers

def liters_needed(t, v): # t: distance in kms, v: fuel consumption
    fuelConsumption = convert_milage(v)
    litersNeeded = (t * fuelConsumption) / 100
    return litersNeeded
```

Error:
http://i54.tinypic.com/2afmu7p.png

Error message:

```
>>> convert_milage(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'convert_milage' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Please add error descriptions into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the console for the file you're in, not just use the general python console, as that knows nothing about the functions in your source file.

Press `Ctrl-Alt-Enter` and select `Current active editor`.

That should import the current module into your shell and make things work better.